# Creating animation from atlas in Phaser 3?

Tags: phaser-framework

I have a multiatlas with different types of images inside:

```
this.load.multiatlas('images', 'images.json', 'images.png');
```

I want to make an animation from a particular set of images inside the atlas, say, `'face1'...'face9'`. How can I target them when creating the animation? I mean, there is a method

```
this.anims.create({
  key: 'faceAnim',
  frames: [ {key: '...'}, {key: '...'} ]
})
```

But I don't know what would be placed inside the 'key' values to make it work. `key: 'face1'` obviously doesn't work, because Phaser needs to know which atlas to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all of the frames you want to use are named starting with `face` in your `images.json` file, you can do this:

```
  this.anims.create({
    key: 'images',
    frames: this.anims.generateFrameNames('images', { prefix: 'face', start:1, end: 9},
    [any other animation config settings you want, repeat, etc.]
  });
```

I'm guessing on the start and end values because I can't see your `images.json` to know how you named everything, but this should get you started down the right path. This [question](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/40210-multiatlas-animation/) might also help.